# Android full screen layout position

Tags: android, android-layout, fullscreen

I got a problem with setting an action to full screen. When I set an action to full screen, the layout was shifted down, it does not draw from the top edge of screen. But it will be fix by itself when I press menu button and the menu shown.

I set it to full screen by following code:
**setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);**

I also make the wallpaper can be visible and hide title bar. It was tested on android 2.1 and 2.2

**simplified Code:**

TestActivity.java :

```
package com.test.fullscreen;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER);

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#66303030"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:hint="Text"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="17dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.fullscreen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".TestActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

**Update:**

I found that if I replace the `EditText` to `TextView`, it works properly. If the EditText is the first `View` to show, the layout will be shifted down.

Comment: add your layout xml here.. and if possible add a screenshot also..

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because you execute super.onCreate after your settings. Try the following:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

       setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that it may cause by Android bugs.

Comment: @user554712 : have you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
requestWindowFeature(FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

[requestWindowFeature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestWindowFeature%28int%29) must be called before you call `setContentView(view)` in your Activity's `onCreate`. Also call the following:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: It seem does not work. I added `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` between "super.onCreate" and "setContentView" but it still cannot fix. Could you describe more detail?